# Java foreach method from second element in LinkedList

Tags: java, foreach, linked-list

I need help with foreach method to LinkedList in Java 8.
I need to start from second element. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [skip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) the first element: `list.stream().skip(1).forEach(...)`. Note that the skipped elements will still be traversed by the stream, so for a random access list such as `ArrayList` it is much more efficient to use a loop starting from the relevant index if this index is very large. In your case it doesn't matter because your starting index is small and your list doesn't support random access.